# Custom view not displaying

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create custom view but it is not loading.

I am trying [Parallelogram view using UIBezierPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496532/parallelogram-view-using-uibezierpath)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var testView: UIView!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let customeView = CustomeView()
        customeView.draw(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        testView.addSubview(customeView)
    }
}

class CustomeView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX , y: bounds.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY))

        path.close()
        UIColor.red.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }
}
```

I am expecting to create custom view.

Answer (score 3):

Never call a view's `draw` method yourself. Remove that line. The proper solution is to give the view a proper frame. And you should set up the view in `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let customeView = CustomeView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    testView.addSubview(customeView)
}
```